2 community pairs. Split pot
I’m confused as to a ruling at my last trip to card room. Player 1 has hole cards A J. Player 2 hole cards A 7.  Community cards end up as 6-6-8-8-A.  Ruling is a chop pot.  However, wouldn’t player 1 have 2 pair, A-A-8-8-J. Player 2 would have 2 pair A-A-8-8-7.  Shouldn’t player 1 win the pot due to the higher 5th card?  If anyone has an explanation, I would appreciate it because I looked like an a hole arguing this.   Thanks

Kicker plays in this case .
